# Fix/Reinstall SQL Native Client?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server

Don't know what happened but on my Windows 7 64bit the connection to SQL2005 using SQL Native client is not working anymore.

More in detail, if I try to connect to the SQL server using oledb it works fine, no matter is from VB.NET, UDL file, MS Access, ODBC etc etc

If I try the same (same user, same server, same database) using SQL Native client, it hangs.
It hangs from a VB.net program, hangs from an UDL file, hangs from ODBC source etc

I tried many things without solving it.
Is there a way to reinstall, fix, restore etc etc Sql Native client?

Comment: Sure;  Just reinstall it..http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793

Comment: thanks, but it didn't solve the issue, other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Following helps me:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2010/08/13/windows-7-appcompat-changes-and-sql-server-client-and-setup-hangs.aspx

In article specified GPO setting "Turn off Switchback Compatibility Engine" under Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Application Compatibility must be set to Not Configured or Disabled! If this setting is set to Enabled, then SQL Server Native Client hangs.